# Access a python script from ASP.NET application

Tags: python, asp.net, nltk

I've a need of running a python script that uses `NLTK` library with it through a ASP.NET application. 
I tried using `IronPython`, tried to package the script to a executable using `cx-freeze` and `py2exe`. All attempts were not successful.

Now my concern is to host the Python script as a RESTful API. The service should run on the local machine. What are the possible methods for this task?

~Edit~
Here's the code I wanna to add up for IronPython

```
#Code modificaiton for standalone python run
#importing libraries
import nltk
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
import re 
import os
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer


#Reading the text from console
print("Enter the text - ")
raw = sys.stdin.readline()


sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(raw)  #split in to sentances
tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences] #split in to words
tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences] #tag sentences with NN, NNP, etc
chunked_sentences = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences, binary=True)

def extract_entity_names(t):
    entity_names = []

    if hasattr(t, 'label') and t.label:
        if t.label() == 'NE':
            entity_names.append(' '.join([child[0] for child in t]))
        else:
            for child in t:
                entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(child))

    return entity_names


entity_names = []
for tree in chunked_sentences:
    entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(tree))


#Check if the output is null  
if not entity_names:
    print("List is empty")
    entity_names.append("NullNER")

# Print unique entity names
print (set(entity_names))

input("Press any key to exit...")
```

Comment: ASP .Net Core? Or you trying to use it with .NET Framework?

Comment: using .NET framework

Comment: okay, IronPython works with .NET Framework. Maybe you could provide a bit of code, so we can see, where your problems are.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger here I've edited the question with the code